# LLN and CLT on $Y_n(t) := \boldsymbol{1}_{X_n \le t}$

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables where $X_1$ has distribution function $F$. Fix $t \in \Bbb R$. Define $Y_n(t) := \boldsymbol{1}_{X_n \le t}$. Certainly, the $Y_n(t)$ are again i.i.d.

Then, $\Bbb P[Y_1(t) = 0] = \Bbb P [\{X_1 > t \}]$ and $\Bbb P[Y_1(t) = 1] = \Bbb P [\{X_1 \le t \}]$. Thus, $\Bbb E[Y_1] = \Bbb P [\{X_n \le t \}]$ and $\Bbb V[Y_1] = \Bbb E[Y_1^2] - \Bbb E[Y_1]^2 = (1 - \Bbb P [\{X_n \le t \}]) \Bbb P [\{X_n \le t \}]$.

Do I see this correctly, that by the Law of large numbers, ${1 \over n}S_n(t) \to \Bbb E[Y_1] \Bbb P$-almost surely, where $S_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n Y_n(t)$?

Next define $S_n^{*}(t) := {1 \over \sqrt{n}}(S_n(t) - \Bbb E[S_n(t)])$. Now I am to use the central limit theorem on $S_n^{*}(t)$ and in my task it says that this can be done by choosing a certain $t \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is correct. Also $S_n^{*}$ converges in distribution to normal with mean $0$ and variance $(1-F(t))F(t)$ for any $t$. There is no need to choose a particular $t$.

Comment: I edited the question: In order to use the CLT, I need to bring the variance to play.

Comment: If you want the limit to be standard normal you have to divide $S_n^{*}$ by the square root of the variance. But you can take the limit without dividing by the variance. In this case it is impossible to get standard normal as the limit because $(1-F(t))F(t)$ can never be $1$ for any value of $t$. But  $S_n^{*}$ does converge in distribution for any $t$.